# Qual é diferença Entre HTML.ActionLink() vs Url.Action()?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, .net, asp.net-mvc-helper

Lendo alguns tutoriais de ASP.NET MVC encontrei esses dois *helpers* sendo utilizados para fazer basicamente a mesma coisa, que era direcionar o usuário para uma nova *view*.

Então gostaria de saber se existe alguma diferença mais notável entre `HTML.ActionLink()` e `Url.Action()`?

Quais são as condições necessárias para usar um ao invés do outro?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> Lendo alguns tutoriais de ASP.NET MVC encontrei esses dois helpers sendo utilizados para fazer basicamente a mesma coisa, que era direcionar o usuário para uma nova view.

Não é isso que eles fazem. A função deles é gerar *links* baseados nas rotas definidas na configuração da sua aplicação. Redirecionamento é feito em *controller*, usando [`RedirectToAction()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.redirecttoaction(v=vs.118).aspx).

> Então gostaria de saber se existe alguma diferença mais notável entre `HTML.ActionLink` e `Url.Action`?

`@Html.ActionLink()` gera uma *tag* `<a>` com um texto simples dentro e alguma configuração, como o *controller*, as *tokens* de rota e alguma configuração HTML, como `class`, `id`, etc.

`@Url.Action` permite que você monte sua lógica (que não precisa ser necessariamente uma *tag* `<a>`) usando o *link* gerado de acordo com a rota. Um caso muito comum é o de você querer criar botões com ícones dentro e querer criar um link para o conjunto:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("MinhaAction", "MeuController")">
    <div class="meu-botao">
        <img src="@Url.Content("~/Images/minha-imagem.jpg")" />
        Um texto dentro do botão
    </div>
</a>
```

> Quais são as condições necessárias para usar um ao invés do outro ?

O objetivo. Se a ideia é apenas um link com texto (que você pode até estilizar na forma de um botão usando CSS), `@Html.ActionLink()` atende bem. Se a ideia é montar um link mais complexo, com imagem dentro, texto ou outros componentes, `@Url.Action()` é melhor.

Answer (score 16):

Bom, o `HTML.ActionLink` gera um `<a href="..."></a>` enquanto `Url.Action` retorna a url

Por exemplo:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Link", "action", "controller", new { id = "123" }, null)
```

gera:

```
<a href="/controller/action/123">Link</a>
```

enquanto:

```
Url.Action("action", "controller", new { id = "123" })
```

gera:

```
/controller/action/123
```

[Fonte(em inglês)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7709001/html-actionlink-vs-url-action-in-asp-net-razor)

Answer (score 6):

Um gera uma *tag* HTML com um *link* completo, o outro gera apenas um URL (parcial):

```
@Html.ActionLink("texto", "action", "controller", new { id = "123" }, null)
```

Produz:

```
<a href="/controller/action/123">texto</a>
```

Já

```
Url.Action("action", "controller", new { id = "123" })
```

Produz apenas:

```
/controller/action/123
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/ASP.NET/ActionLink.cs).

[Fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7709015/221800).